# Conditional variable thread sync

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads, mutex

I am trying to use `pthread_cond_wait()` for FIFO waiting queue.
I have parking lots and cars. Each lot has a capacity. After the capacity is reached the cars should wait in a queue and when new space is available a new car should park in that lot in FIFO manner.
What I want to achieve is

```
//thread1
if(Park capacity is not reached)
coming car parks to lot
else
coming car is added to the queue
if(a car leaves the lot )
signal thread 2

//thread2
while(no signal from thread1)
pthread_cond_wait()
oldcar = dequeue
oldcar parks to lot
```

Basically, my problem is when to send signal to thread 2. If I send the signal when the capacity is reached, It won't do good because we cannot let the car park without dequeuing first.

I have one more question, these functionalities are required in a function called Park. But I created my threads much earlier than calling this function. Where should I create these threads? In the Park function or in the main function in which I created all my threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend restructuring your code.  Currently both thread1 and thread2 can park cars, but really it is best if you put the parking cars to thread2 and always queue cars for the lot.

There should be two methods on your initial thread:

```
void carWantsToPark(Car* car) {
    enqueueCar(car);
    signal thread2
}


void carWantsToLeave(Car* car) {
    removeCarFromLot(car); // removes car from lot
    signal thread2;
}
```

Thread 2:

```
void execThread() {
    bool threadAlive=true;
    event event_array[2];
    event_array[0]=trigger_lot_event;
    event_array[1]=trigger_death;
    do {
        triggerIndex=await_multiple_events(event_array);
        if (triggerIndex==1) {
            threadAlive=false;
            continue;
        }
        if (len(parking_queue)>0) {
            Car* car=dequeueCar();
            addCarToLot(car);
        }
    }
    while(threadAlive);
}

// Other methods shared between threads.  Ensure to synchronise access to collections
void enqueueCar(Car* car) {
      // Add car to queue
}


Car* dequeueCar() {
    // Dequeue car and return 
   return dequeuedCar;
}

void addCarToLot(Car* car) {
}

void removeCarFromLot(Car* car) {
}
```

I would start the threads as close to needing them as possible - if there is a chance the threads are not needed by your program, it is best if they are not started at all.  Note also I have included a `trigger_death` event in this pseudocode, that would have to be set up with `trigger_lot_event` when you initialise the threads.  Triggering `trigger_death` should kill thread 2.